# Rails nil when reading active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, null

i have this in my template

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
<li><%= link_to client.name, :controller => "client", :action => "show", :id => client.id %></li>
<%=YAML::dump(client.lastfull)%>
<% end %>
```

where client looks like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
        set_table_name 'client'
        alias_attribute :id, :clientid
        set_primary_key :clientid


        has_many :jobs, :foreign_key => 'clientid', :order => 'starttime DESC'

        def lastfull
                jobs.first
        end
end
```

this works and this is output :

```
--- !ruby/object:Job attributes: jobid: "81" name: dobrak comment: "" endtime: 2012-06-20 10:15:04
```

But when i try to read any of the attributes i get error:

```
undefined method `jobid' for nil:NilClass
```

Job class:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessor :jobid

        set_table_name 'job'
        belongs_to :client

        has_one :status, :primary_key => 'jobstatus', :foreign_key => 'jobstatus'
end
```

i tried to add method jobid which return attribute and adding attr_accessor, but nothing worked for me. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Rails 2.3.5

Comment: Tead any attributes where? How is `@clients` being assigned?

Comment: in home_controller: @clients = Client.find(:all)
Reading in template: <%=YAML::dump(client.lastfull.jobid)%>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are clients without any jobs. What happens if you change the line to something like `<%= client.lastfull.present? ? YAML::dump(client.lastfull.jobid) : 'client has no jobs' %>`? You can also take a look at [`Object#try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)

Comment: client.lastfull.present? has a better syntax to write: client.lastfull?

Comment: `lastfull` is a method that DominickM defined himself, so a corresponding `?` method wouldn't exist in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition before outputting result of client#lastfull in a view like this:

```
<% if client.lastfull %>
  output job info here like <%= lastfull.jobid %> etc.
<% else %>
  no jobs available
<% end %>
```